# Revoke access to postgres database for a role

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have created a separate role "newrole" and new schema "newschema" for a certain user that should only execute some stored functions. I have managed to revoke access to schema "public" for the current database.

Logged in as "newrole" I still have access to postgres database like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_user
```

I want to revoke all access to the postgres database and tried following that not work:

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE postgres FROM newrole
```

When logged in as newrole I can still read the postgres database.

How do I revoke any access to the postgres admin database?

I have searched a long time but not found anything regarding access to the postgres admin database.

TIA,

Comment: What user do you want to remove? All users?

Comment: Only the "newrole". Normal users does not access the database directly and sometimes need access to the postgres database for other reasons.

Comment: I believe the connect privilege needs to be specified, try REVOKE connect ON DATABASE [dbname] FROM public

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with database `postgres`. Instead, you want to manipulate the **catalog** of the current database. Every database has a catalog of information on all objects in schema `pg_catalog`, and in standards-compliant form in schema `information_schema`, so you should restrict access to those for the role in question and also for the `public` role because every role is also member of that role:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM newrole;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM public;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA information_schema FROM newrole;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA information_schema FROM public;
```

However, the system does not always honour this accross-the-board restriction, the catalogs are there for a reason and provide important functions in the database. Particularly functions may still execute.

In general, you do not want to fiddle with the catalogs unless **you really know what you are doing**.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But the "newrole" can still access pg_users etc. Is there no way to hide sensitive information (i e multi-tenant environment)?

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to run this:

```
select *  FROM information_schema.table_privileges where grantee = 'newrole';
```

to display all the privileges for newrole.  With that information you should be able to explicitly revoke everything other than access to 'newschema'

Comment: @sibert I have removed my answer becuase I dont know what I am doing... Sorry If you ran my command and it caused any problems. Good luck with your project

Comment: For some reason there is no information about "newrole" in the table_privileges. So I am still searching...