# Postgres revoke database access from user

Tags: postgresql

When I tried

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE postgres from admin;
```

but the user `admin` is still able to connect to `postgres` remotely via `pgadmin` after that.

How do I completely revoke an user's access to a database?

```
/root$ psql -U postgres
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 admin     | No inheritance                                 | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}

postgres=# REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE postgres from admin; 
REVOKE
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
 datid | datname  |  pid   | usesysid | usename  | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |
          query_start          |         state_change          | waiting | state  |              query              
-------+----------+--------+----------+----------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+--------+---------------------------------
 12924 | postgres | 121487 |       10 | postgres | psql             |             |                 |          -1 | 2018-03-10 20:20:42.458031+08 | 2018-03-10 20:21:27.367078+08 |
 2018-03-10 20:21:27.367078+08 | 2018-03-10 20:21:27.367082+08 | f       | active | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
(1 row)

postgres=# \q
/root$ psql -U admin postgres
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revoke access to postgres database for a role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232458/revoke-access-to-postgres-database-for-a-role)

Comment: @SepehrGH the answers there still allows the user to see the existence of the database (and hence can attempt to connect). I want to hide the database completely from the user.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You probably also need to do a

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres FROM PUBLIC;
```

Each role is an implicit member of PUBLIC.

Comment: This does prevent user from connecting to the database! But it is still able to see the existence of the database (and hence can attempt to connect). Is there a way to hide the existence of the database completely from an user?

Comment: Not within a single instance (you could run multiple instances). Why do you want to? (Obscurity is not security)

Comment: I just prefer not to let the user know about the existence of other DBs (this is possible in MySQL). I guess I'll have to run multiple instances then...

Comment: ```PUBLIC``` is a virtual role?

Comment: @Eelke While obscurity is definitely not security, obscurity does stop a naive dev asking for access to a database they shouldn't access, triggering naive managers to schedule expensive meetings to discuss why dev shouldn't have access.